# C++ : Confused in dealing with multiple classes

Tags: c++, data-structures, avl-tree

This is the first time i m trying to handle multiple classes in a c++ program and the experience has been really terrible because i have spent many tens of hours just staring at the code and trying to figure out whats wrong.  Also, my actual code currently is about 600 lines so I will just put up the relevant code to what bothers me the most and try explain it.

I am having a class for a multiway-search-tree called node. And My aim is to use an AVL tree(class name Avlnode) as an index tree(containing words in a sorted order and address of the corresponding node at every Avlnode) in order to do operations on the multi-way-tree in O(log n) time.
Now consider this code fragment

```
//Basically searches for a string in Avl tree with root t and returns pointer 
//to the   corresponding node in the multi-way tree 

node* Avlnode::Avlsearch(string x,Avlnode* t)
{
    if (t==NULL)
    {
        cout<<"why you search whats not in string";//invalid search
        exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
        if(isLess(x,t->element)) //isLess compares strings and works good
        {                        //element refers to the string stored in Avlnode
            Avlsearch(x,t->left);
        }
        else if (isLess(t->element,x))
        {
            Avlsearch(x,t->right);
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<"found";  
            cout<<t->index->empname;
            return t->index; //its fine till here
        }
    }
}

//basically adds child under the boss in multi-way tree, by searching for the
//address of boss first using the AVL tree

void node::insertunderboss(string child, string boss,Avlnode* obj1)
{
    node* temp=obj1->Avlsearch(boss, obj1->root); //root=root of Avltree
//why is address of temp and t->index not the same??
    cout<<temp;
    cout<<"root current is "<<obj1->root->element;
    cout<<"\n"<<temp->empname; //empname is string stored in node
 //this refuses to work even though t->index->empname worked perfect.
 // in my first function t->index->empname gave me a string
 // I just stored t->index inside temp
 //But temp->empname makes cmd hang. Your program has stopped working. 
    node* c=insertemp(child,temp);
    cout<<"last check";
    obj1->Avlinsert(c,obj1->root);
    return;
}
```

I hope my question was clear. I thought of passing by reference but I cannot figure out why this does not work, logically it looks alright.
Any kind of help would be really appreciated.

Comment: pardon my ignorance, but what's wrong with std::map?

Comment: No your question isn't clear! 1st: extract it from your code smple (leave the comment as a hint). 2nd Explain what happens (_'doesn't work'_ is not a helpful description!)

Comment: Is `t->index` a node*? index usually indicates an int which conflicts with the return type of your function. Additionally two of your branches don't return at all in that function alone. This won't even compile.

Comment: pardon mine as well, but whats with the node-**parameter** to the search-function? You *have* a node already: `*this`.

Comment: The questions are completely unclear to me. Why should 'address of temp and t->index' be the same? I can't even see any relationship. Also as usual 'refuses to work' means very little.

Comment: @John, I just returned t->index from first function and in the 2nd function 1st statement I equated it to temp. So they should be similar in my opinion(of course thats not what is happening). I fixed the 'refuses to work' part.

Comment: @bathsheba, Nothing wrong. I am supposed to do it this way for a programming assignment .

Comment: @Mcaden, t->index is node* yes. This is just a part of my program. As i said, the actual code is much larger and I dont think anybody here on this forum would have the time to read through all of it.

Comment: You should probably implement functions based on the `std::map` design then rather than inventing your own names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are missing return statements, this is an improvement

```
node* Avlnode::Avlsearch(string x,Avlnode* t)
{
    if (t==NULL)
{
    cout<<"why you search whats not in string";//invalid search
    exit(0);
}
else
{
    if(isLess(x,t->element)) //isLess compares strings and works good
    {                        //element refers to the string stored in Avlnode
        return Avlsearch(x,t->left);
        ^^^^^^
    }
    else if (isLess(t->element,x))
    {
        return Avlsearch(x,t->right);
        ^^^^^^
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"found";  
        cout<<t->index->empname;
        return t->index; //its fine till here
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Ohhhh. I could never see that in my life. Thankyou sooooooo much man. Now everything makes sense except me.